# accessing std::tuple element by constexpr in type

Tags: c++, c++20, stdtuple, compile-time-constant

I would like to access to a tuple element at compile time by a value constexpr in the type

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

struct A {
    static constexpr int id = 1;
    void work() {
            std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    static constexpr int id = 2;
    void work() {
            std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    std::tuple<A,B> t = std::make_tuple(a,b);

    static constexpr int search_id = 2;

    auto& item = std::get< ? ( T::id == search_id ) ? >(t);
    item.work();
    return 0;
}
```

I guess using  `std::apply` and test would be a runtime search...
I'm using c++20

Comment: Are the types unique? Can you share your `std::apply`-based solution?

Comment: type are different, sorry I can not figure out how to format comment, but apply would be like the solution proposed below...I just can not understand how iterating trought values will allow to access directly to the right element at compile time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `constrexpr` function to get index:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t get_index(int id)
{
    constexpr int ids[] = {Ts::id...};

    const auto it = std::find(std::begin(ids), std::end(ids), id);

    // Handle absent id.
    if (it == std::end(ids)) {
        throw std::runtime("Invalid id");
    }
    // You can also possibly handle duplicate ids.

    return std::distance(std::begin(ids), it);
}

template <int id, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto& get_item(std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
{
    return std::get<get_index<Ts...>(id)>(t);
}
template <int id, typename... Ts>
constexpr const auto& get_item(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
{
    return std::get<get_index<Ts...>(id)>(t);
}
```

and then

```
auto& item = get_item<search_id>(t);
```

Comment: thank you very much, but as far as I understand  std::find won't be compute at compile-time, so the position of element will be calculated at runtime, isn't it?

Comment: [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is `constexpr` since C++20 (for previous standard, you have to write your own version :( ). The index selection is actually done at compile time, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `std::get` a single element, you can use `std::apply` to iterate over the elements of the tuple and perform operations based on the element type

```
A a;
B b;
auto t = std::make_tuple(a, b);
static constexpr int search_id = 2;

std::apply([](auto&... items) {
  ([]<class T>(T& item) {
    if constexpr (T::id == search_id)
      item.work();
  }(items), ...);
}, t);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oj1M1sTsq)

If you really want to get a single tuple element with a specific `id` value, you can still use `std::apply` to expand the `id` of all elements and find the offset of the value equal to `search_id` as the template parameter of `std::get`

```
auto& item = std::apply([&t]<class... Args>(const Args&... items) -> auto& {
  constexpr auto id = [] {
    std::array ids{Args::id...};
    return ids.end() - std::ranges::find(ids, search_id);
  }();
  return std::get<id>(t);
}, t);

item.work();
```

Comment: thanks, but I guess in this case we are accessing each element of the tuple , so it s not a compile time access, isn't it?

Comment: All element access is done at compile-time since the index must be a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 2):

This is a prime candidate for [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction), which can be used to perform a compile-time linear search; you just need a helper type to act as the predicate:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, auto Id, auto I, typename U = std::tuple_element_t<I, T>>
    struct get_by_id_pred : std::bool_constant<std::remove_cvref_t<U>::id == Id> {
        static constexpr auto index = I;
    };
}

template<int Id>
constexpr auto&& get_by_id(auto&& t) noexcept {
    using tuple_t = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>;
    return [&]<auto ...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) -> auto&& {
        using res = std::disjunction<detail::get_by_id_pred<tuple_t, Id, Is>...>;
        static_assert(res::value, "id not found");
        return std::get<res::index>(decltype(t)(t));
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<tuple_t>>{});
}

...

auto& item = get_by_id<search_id>(t);
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wrxv7MMKz)**</kbd>